# chatter must be closed automatically when liveagent goes to offline means

Tags: chatter

I  am  Sri working with service console app  in salesforce.com and i am using these app for my call center application when live agent is online means for customer..one link is provide by using that link he/she chatting with live agent.when agent goes to offline means the chat box automatically closed. for customer how it is possible..how can i achieve this..which technique i have to use it.

Comment: The Customer Will get a message that the Chat has disconnected if the Agent goes offline. (I believe there is a timeout)